# pymc imput passing back 1e20

Tags: python, pymc

Can't tell if I am doing something wrong with pymc's impute functionality or if this is a bug. Impute via the masked array passes 1e20 values to missing elements, while the inefficient method Impute seems to pass back correct samples. Below is a small example.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as py

disasters_array = np.random.random((3,3))
disasters_array[1,1]=None

# The inefficient way, using the Impute function:
D = py.Impute('D', py.Normal, disasters_array, mu=.5, tau=1E5)

# The efficient way, using masked arrays:
# Generate masked array. Where the mask is true,
# the value is taken as missing.
print disasters_array
masked_values = np.ma.masked_invalid(disasters_array)

# Pass masked array to data stochastic, and it does the right thing
disasters = py.Normal('disasters', mu=.5, tau=1E5, value=masked_values, observed=True)
@py.deterministic
def test(disasters=disasters, D=D):
    print D
    print disasters

mcmc = py.MCMC(py.Model(set([test,disasters])))
```

Output:

Original Matrix:

```
[[ 0.23507836  0.2024624   0.90518228]
 [ 0.95816            **nan**  0.43145808]
 [ 0.99566308  0.25431568  0.25464137]]
```

D with imputations:

```
[[array(0.23507836309832741) array(0.20246240248367342)
  array(0.9051822818081371)]
 [array(0.9581599997650212) **array(0.5005324083232756)**
  array(0.43145807852698237)]
 [array(0.9956630757864052) array(0.2543156788973996)
  array(0.25464136701826867)]]
```

Masked Array approach:

```
[[  2.35078363e-01   2.02462402e-01   9.05182282e-01]
 [  9.58160000e-01   **1.00000000e+20**   4.31458079e-01]
 [  9.95663076e-01   2.54315679e-01   2.54641367e-01]]
```

Comment: `1+20` is the default `fill_value` for a Numpy MaskedArray. Try working through the entire exercise using both methods (e.g., sample and plot the results). Then you'll see if there is a difference.

Comment: @inversion, Interesting, fill_value being passed, I think, adds evidence this is a bug in pymc's masked array imputation. The above example is notional because I am working on a larger problem and was seeing 1e20 in the outputs and tracked it to the masking/imputation, and wanted something small to show to the community.

Comment: In addition, Tried using the below, but it returns a masked array with improper dimensions.
masked_values = np.ma.masked_values(disasters_array, value=None)

mask = False,

Comment: I wasn't able to determine why pymc was passing 1e-20 instead of a random sample, but I was able to circumvent the problem by changing the data type passed to the stochastic. More information here: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/49